# python-rrdtool, how to create graphs in UTC time zone

Tags: python, graph, rrdtool, rrd

I am using python-rrdtool to generate graphs from rrd files, it is by default generating graphs in CST time zone. How can i change the default time zone to UTC.

I found that setting the TZ env variable can do the trick. How can i do this using python-rrdtool ?

I followed this [tutorial](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/prog/rrdpython.en.html) to create graphs using python-rrdtool

Thank You

Comment: If you found that setting `TZ` works, why not just do that, then? e.g. `TZ=UTC python-rrdtool ....`?

Comment: I tried setting TZ env variable, but it didn't helped, python-rrdtool is a python wrapper for rrdtool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution,

To set the TZ variable using python, you need to add the below lines to your python script where you are generating your rrd graphs -

```
import time, os
os.environ['TZ'] = "Asia/Kolkata"   # timezone you want to display graphs in
time.tzset()
```